# Render individual item and collection of items in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, arguments, enumerable

How can I display the details for a task in the same way (using my _task partial) whether the view is using `@project.tasks` (ie multiple) or just `@task` (ie individual task)?

My question is similar to this one : [How can you make a ruby function accept either an individual item or collection of items and do the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680000/how-can-you-make-a-ruby-function-accept-either-an-individual-item-or-collection)

I tried checking `if @project.tasks.is_a?` but it complained `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but I understood that you want to render partial either collection on individual item. So if I right you should follow these steps and everything will work out of box. Let's say you have model `Project` and it `has_many` `Tasks`, the steps are:

1. Rename your task partial to `tasks/_task.html.erb`
2. Use in view (e.g. `projects/show.html.erb`) render like this: `<%= render @project.tasks %>`
3. You able to use also render like this: `<%= render @task %>`

Note: solution works for `Rails >= 3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the object is an array or not use `if @project.tasks.is_a?(Array)`